# AFCI breaker issue

Tags: wiring, receptacle, afci

I finished my basement and installed an AFCI breaker for my outlets. I have 12 outlets on the breaker. I passed all electrical inspections and all seemed well. I had used some of the outlets with no issue. However, when I went to use the #10 outlet in the series, the breaker tripped. I then found that the final 3 outlets all cause the breaker to trip (#9 works fine)At first I thought it may be due to the vacuum I was using, however, even a small draw trips the breaker.

I changed out outlet #10, but nothing changed. I can see half the run between #9 and 10 and the wiring looks ok. What would cause this?  Should I try to replace the wiring in between 9 and 10?

Comment: I would check outlet #9 for a loose connection. Did you use backstab outlets, if so, you naughty boy! LOL   Pigtailing is best practice. Also the outlets with clamp type connections are easy to use. Just put both wires on each side on the same clamp (they support up to two wires.

Comment: Random comment:  With everything I've learned here and all the problems back stab outlets and switches have, I think they shouldn't be code legal anymore.  The electrical industry has made so much progress in safety over the years as in GFCIs, AFCIs, Dual function AFCI/GFCI breakers, etc. that I wonder why we are still allowing this relic of a wiring method that's caused so many issues.????

Comment: AFCI’s in a basement ? What code version are you under? If AFCI the problem can be on the receptacle prior a loose connection is all it takes.

Comment: I agree the problem could be at #9 (or even #8 if #9 is unused). How did you inspect the wiring?  Because there's no earthly way to inspect a backstab.  Were the screws "good-n-tight"?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you wired them, the problem could be in the box with outlet #9, the box with outlet #10, or in between them. Check the boxes first because that's easier, and if that doesn't fix the problem, look into replacing the wiring between 9 and 10.

AFCIs can be very finicky, but you **can** figure out what the problem is by thorough troubleshooting. Just make sure you're changing only one thing at a time in each test.

Comment: I agree a loose connection can be the cause. I have thought backstabs should have been removed from code 30 years ago as the high 90% of the electrical failures have been from backstabbing. +